# Using this lever puzzle, how would I make my piston door turn OFF when the puzzle is correct? [MC1.14.2]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Basically, I am making a beta design for a security mechanism which I will use in a survival server. I want to make it so that when the puzzle is completed, it will turn OFF rather than ON. Therefore, the doors will open rather than close. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D2rorb6mRyQ) is the video which I use as a guide, and [this](https://mega.nz/#F!b2AiVISZ!94elU-vnZJ5ZkkUvEkej1A) is a copy of the map I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is remove the signal inverter that uses a redstone torch. Here it is in the video tutorial (at 5:30):

[image: Redstone inverter.]

All you have to do is replace the torch with redstone, like this:

[image: Like this.]

As you can see, the doors are now open, even though the visible redstone is powered off. You can do everything else as it is in the video.